# Java NIO library, api ...?

Tags: java, api, tcp, jar, nio

Can anyone suggest some good java library that can help me easily create non-blocking server and client. I was searching on the internet i found 2 solution that so far didn't get me anywhere:

1 . XSockets http://xsocket.org/

Great library but you cannot set the tcp client socket to reuse the socket if u are trying to reconnect (I must wait some time until the port is free to reconnect, this happens if u must use predefined port for ex 6789). Also u cannot download the source code to modify it.

2 .  Kyronet https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet

Great library, you can download the source code and modify it. The support is great, i get answers on the forum max after 1 hour. When u communicate with java server and client that use kyronet there are no problems, but when u try to connect to a VB6 or C TCP server it gets complicated and throws some funny errors like "Unable to read object larger than read buffer: 1466262560" witch appears when u try to connect with a server (the both server are just accepting my connection and not sending anything).

I would like to try more solution like this two, and if i find i will post my impressions and test result here. Hope you can share some knowledge about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know [netty](http://netty.io/) is the most popular tool in this field.